# Sorting dictionary keys for the equal values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is formed by using counter:

```
c = collections.Counter()
for y in all_years:  # iterator
    c[y] += 1
d = dict(c.most_common())
print(d)
```

/*All years contain list of 250 year values*/

The result: {1995: 9, 1957: 7, 2003: 7, 2000: 7, 2001: 6, 1975: 6, 2014: 6, 2009: 6, 1994: 5, 1999: 5, 2010: 5, 2002: 5, 1997: 5}

Is it possible to sort this dictionary for the equal values by year:
e.g. {1995:9,1957:7,2000:7, 2003:7, 1975:6, 2001:6, 2014:6 etc}

Comment: Yes, use an `OrderedDict` on version < 3.6.

Comment: @vaultah `most_common`'s output is sorted by counts (by default)

Comment: 1. Why? 2. Your loop kinda beats the purpose of using `Counter`. Just write `c = Counter(all_years)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not a dupe of that question. The OP wants to sort the dictionary by keys, too.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but it returns such a result:(1995, 9), (1957, 7), (2003, 7), (2000, 7), (2001, 6), (1975, 6), (2014, 6), (2009, 6),

Comment: @SM See an edit to my answer for an improvement to your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a high level breakdown of what you'd need to do to get your expected result.

1. When building your `Counter`, just pass `all_years`.
2. Dictionaries in python <3.6 are not ordered by default, so you'll need to use an `OrderedDict`.
3. When sorting, make sure you sort by multiple predicates - **value** first, followed by the **key**.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

c = Counter(all_years)
r = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))

OrderedDict([(1995, 9),
             (1957, 7),
             (2000, 7),
             (2003, 7),
             (1975, 6),
             (2001, 6),
             (2009, 6),
             (2014, 6),
             (1994, 5),
             (1997, 5),
             (1999, 5),
             (2002, 5),
             (2010, 5)])
```

Thanks to Stefan Pochmann for the improvement.

To explain a bit more about `key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`, this is how it works:

- You want to sort pairs by the values. So, `x[1]` comes first. You also want to sort in descending order, so negate it. Since `x[1]` is guaranteed to be counts, this should work for any `Counter` output
- Next, you want to sort by years, so `x[0]` comes next.

---

In python 3.6, just pass the result of `sorted` to the `dict` constructor -

```
r = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
```

The dictionary is built in the order that pairs are passed to it.